# How can I get the URL of any new website that the user visits?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently trying to create an extension that keeps track of the number of times a user visits certain websites. For example, if the user opens a tab and navigates to https://www.facebook.com/, `chrome.storage` updates to reflect this change (the integer value for the key https://www.facebook.com/ increases by 1).

Right now, I am using `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` to listen for URL changes and update `chrome.storage` accordingly. However, this listener also fires when a tab is closed (resulting in two updates of that website, one for visiting it and one for closing it).

I tried using `chrome.tabs.onCreated`, but I need to listen for changes within tabs (which this listener doesn't provide).

My question is, how can I update `chrome.storage` only when the user visits the website (and not when the user closes the tab with the website)?

Comment: can you differentiate between open and closed by looking at the event properties?

Comment: @dandavis Nope. The tab object or the listener doesn't tell you if the tab is being closed (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab, https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onCreated).

Comment: looking at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab, it seems like _active_, _status_, and _width_ would all vary based on open/close, but i can't test. also, if _id_ doesn't change, then it's 2nd appearance implies a close.

Comment: I'm not seeing chrome.tabs.onUpdated firing when the tab is closed, can you post your JavaScript so I can try to re-create?

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the help! I just realized a silly mistake I made. The problem was not in the listener. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @dandavis Please see the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized my mistake. Apparently, another function I made was calling the storage functionality of the extension, resulting in the duplicate entries.

For future reference, this is the code I used to check for the new URLs that the user visits:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
      console.log(tab.url);
    }
});
```

Comment: That's correct - I thought for a moment that your mistake might be that onUpdated is called twice - once for loading and once for complete but looks like you've got that covered!